# flat module and injective of ring homomorphism

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $f: R \rightarrow S$ be an injective ring homomorphism.
Suppose $S/J$ is flat over $R$ for every ideal $J$ of $S$. Show that for any ideal $I$ of $R$ for any ideal $J$ of $S$, we
have $(IS) \cap J = IJ$.

Here is my approach:we have injective and surjective  $IS \hookrightarrow S \twoheadrightarrow S/J$ and the kenel($IS\to S/J$) is $IS\cap J$ so we get injective $IS/(IS\cap J) \hookrightarrow S/J$ and by $S/J$ is flat over R, we have the injective $(IS/(IS\cap J))\otimes_R S/J \hookrightarrow S/J\otimes_R S/J$.

It is also obvious the $IJ \subset IS\cap J $
How can we show the other side.
thanks a lot.

Comment: The assumption holds for all ideals $J$ of $S$, but in the claim there is only one ideal $J$. Maybe we can weaken the assumption that $S/J$ is flat only for this specific $J$? Can you please check the original form of the claim?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I think it is arbitrary J, and I edited, thanks.

Comment: @lee Sorry, on second glance I realized the thing I wanted doesn't work.